# Can i extend an ERC721 function?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I wonder is it is possible to extend the ERC721 functions that handles transfering tokens. I want to have a variable, and change its state if an nft has been transferred to someone else. Is that possible, without breaking the ERC721 standard? If possible, how would i exactly do that?

I saw this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/extend-erc721-without-breaking-standard), but it doesnt really answer my question if it is possible and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. And we definitely welcome your innovation and extension here.

In your smart contract you will just use an existing ERC-721 implementation, inherit from that contract and then implement your function something like this:

```
function _transfer(...) {
   // Update a counter for the token recipient
   super._transfer(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what function is called when someone buys an nft from someone else on opensea? I assume it is some of the transfer functions, but it is like 3 or 4 of them.

Comment: The ERC-721 functions that are called are `transferFrom` or `safeTransferFrom`. However, depending on which implementation of ERC-721 you are using, there may a be an internal `_transfer` inside which is the preferred override point.

Comment: Yea, but i want to implement something that happens, after a user has bought an nft on opensea. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Please use a new question for that.